# How to call one class1 from another class2?

Tags: java

Actually am new to Java,How to call one class1 from another class2?
Class1 has main() and other methods.Class2 has different methods.
I want to call class1 from Class2. Please provide the syntax.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to post your code in order for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create an object of type class2 and call the methods of it from main method of class1.

```
class2 c = new class2();
c.methodOfClass2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following classes:

```
public class A {
   int a1 = 15;

   public void showMessage() {
         System.out.println("Hey!");
     }
}

public class B {

}
```

In case you want your class B to be able to read `a1` and call `showMessage()`, you need to create an object of the class they belong, in the class you'll be working in. Like this:

```
public class A {
   int a1 = 15;

   public void showMessage() {
         System.out.println("Hey!");
     }
}

public class B {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
           A a = new A();
           //call either variables or methods by putting 
           //a. in front of them
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To call methods of Class1 from Class2

1. If **`static`** method, call by className. e.g - `Class1.staticMethodToBeCalledFromClass2();`
2. If **`non-static`** method, you need to create object of Class1. e.g - `Class1 cls1 = new Class1(); cls1.nonStaticMethodToBeCalledFromClass2();`

Assuming Your code :

```
public class Class1{
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        }

        public void nonStaticMethodTobeCalledFromClass2() {

        }

        public static void staticMethodTobeCalledFromClass2() {

        }
    }

    public class Class2 {
        public void callClass1Here() {
            Class1 cls1 = new Class1();
            cls1.nonStaticMethodTobeCalledFromClass2();

            Class1.staticMethodTobeCalledFromClass2();
        }
    }
```

If you look at the code, you will see, to call

Comment: This helps, Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome @KarthikBs. Your one upvote for my work will inspire me more. :)